# Random Forest: Effect of Number of Samples in Each Class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have been doing some experiments with the sklearn RandomForestClassifier. I am training multiple trees on multiple batches and merging them using:

```
def combine_rfs(rfList):
   rf1 = rfList[0]

   for i in range(1,len(rfList)):
      rf1.estimators_ += rfList[i].estimators_
   rf1.n_estimators = len(rf1.estimators_)

   return rf1
```

I noticed that if I give an equal number of samples in category A and category B, the classification of the final tree tends to be 40-60% category A, and 40-60% category B, despite that I would have expected it to be much more in A, and less in B.

Basically what I am seeing is that the proportion of samples in A/B will dictate the proportion of classifications for these categories, no matter what the actual proportion of these categories in the test data.

How can I mitigate this effect?

Comment: I can't give you a solution unfortunately, but maybe hint you into the right direction. Sounds like a classical class imbalance problem, so maybe searching for more information on the topic of class imbalance in random forests could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [stratified cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold), a method where you ensure that relative class frequencies are the same in your test and validation data set.

It makes sense that if your train set consists of a lot of category B relatively, that your classifier will predict more of that instance. Stratified cross-validation overcomes this problem by making the three set (train, test, validation) more alike.